# How can I get Gparted to shrink NTFS partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, windows-10, macbook-air

I have been trying to dual boot my 2008 Macbook Air with Windows 10 and Ubuntu. The 16.04 live DVD boots but does not offer the option to install alongside Windows 10. When I try Gparted to shrink the Windows partition, it doesn't let me. I even tried shrinking the partition in Windows, this worked but then the Ubuntu installed didn't recognise that the partition had shrunk, nor did GParted. Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/a/73819/602680) could help.

Comment: Open Disks and check the SMART data for the HDD, to make sure it's not a hardware issue.

Comment: If you are using Mac OS then be aware that it uses a hybrid partition table (Both MSDOS/MBR and GUID Partition Table GPT).  You can re-sync the GPT partition entries to the MSDOS partition table with the following command:  **sudo gptsync /path-to-disk-device**  Where /path-to-disk-device is something like /dev/sdb

Comment: Its a clean Windows install as I had a new SSD and no Mac OSX 10.5 disk anymore. These machines only go up to 10.7 anyway.

Comment: My latest theory is that it was fast boot leaving the partitions mounted so they couldn't be modified. I will test this when I get home...

Comment: @SimonBaldwin can you remember the outcome?

Comment: I gave up and did a clean install of Windows 10, now downgraded to Windows 8 as the Air didn't like the newest upgrades. I also tried Ubuntu and Linux Mint in this computer but it never worked as well as with Windows 8! A weirdness.